# В использования Fetch() Что делать чтобы прошедший вопрос был уделен (или заменит) и появился новый результат?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть такой тестовый код(Js):

```js
function getGIfs() {
  const API = "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=";
  const KEY = "&api_key=37MMWmtaxtdC0DAQazK2JCqGizFbCBJz&limit=10";
  var q = document.getElementById('input').value;
  fetch(API + q + KEY)
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })



    .then(responseJSON => {
      var giffs = responseJSON.data;
      for (i in giffs)

      {
        document.getElementById('IdName').innerHTML =
          ("<img src='" + giffs[i].images.original.url + "' style ='height:150px; width:150px; margin:20px;'/>")
      }
    })

}
```

```html
и HTML код

<div id="Name">
  <h1 id="H1"> Giphy API </h1>
  <input id="input" /><br>
  <button onclick="getGIfs()" id="button"> Поиск</button><br>
  <div id="IdName"></div>
</div>
```

Когда использую `document.write` он правильно работает. Получает 10 гиф элементов. А когда использую `document.getElementById('IdName').innerHTML=` тогда получает это код 1 гиф элемент.
А в `document.getElementById('IdName').appendChild=` и в `document.getElementById('IdName').innerHTML+=` он добавить до бесконечности, мне надо чтобы прошедший поиск удалена и появился новый результат. 
Что мне делать чтобы он работал правильно? 
Чтобы код был меньше не хочу сделать другую функцию(скрипт) Или надо обязательно сделать функцию(скрипт)?

Comment: `=` замени на `+=`

Comment: Да это помогло спасибо! Я думал ошибка в fetch().. И это не дубликат же? Вопрос был другой)) Я просто думал ошибка в  fetch() или в Giphy API..

Comment: То что ты думал, что ошибка в другом, не меняет того, что это дубликат.

Comment: Oкей. Извиняюсь.  Но он не заменил  прошедший поиск. Мне надо чтобы  он заменил прошедший вопрос. Для этого надо отдельную функции писать?

Comment: нет, достаточно перед циклом присвоить пустую строку в innerHTML

Comment: Все помогло, работает! Спасибо. Если можно отметьте дубликат? Как-то не нравиться.)) И спасибо за помощь!